# how to add conditionals in html attribute

Tags: python, django

I am using django 4.1.4 and I am new to it.

In a form I want to set the correct url based on the variable 'update'. If the variable is True, then the template is used for update (in this case a different url), else save new data.

I created something like this:

```
<form action="{% if update %} {% url 'in.edit_session' session.id %} {% else %} {% url 'in.save_session' %} {% endif %}" method="POST" class="form">
```

but is not working.

This will work... but I don't want to duplicate code:

```
  {% if update %}       
        <form action="{% url 'in.edit_session' session.id %}" method="POST" class="form">
    {% else %}       
        <form action="{% url 'in.save_session' %}" method="POST" class="form">
    {% endif %}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete spaces between brackets. It is html after all.

```
<form action="{% if update %}{% url 'in.edit_session' session.id %}{% else %}{% url 'in.save_session' %}{% endif %}" method="POST" class="form">
```